# Create a new column in Pandas dataframe by arbitrary function over rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe. I want to add a column to the dataframe, where the value in the new column is dependent on other values in the row.

What is an efficient way to go about this?

## Example

#### Begin

Start with this dataframe (let's call it `df`), and a dictionary of people's roles.

```
   first         last
--------------------------
0  Jon           McSmith
1  Jennifer      Foobar
2  Dan           Raizman
3  Alden         Lowe


role_dict = {
    "Raizman": "sales",
    "McSmith": "analyst",
    "Foobar": "analyst",
    "Lowe": "designer"
}
```

### End

We have a dataframe where we've 'iterated' over each row, and used the `last_name` to lookup values from our role_dict and add that value to each row as `role`.

```
   first         last       role
--------------------------------------
0  Jon           McSmith    analyst
1  Jennifer      Foobar     analyst
2  Dan           Raizman    sales
3  Alden         Lowe       designer
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is using series [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function since the role is a dictionary

```
df['role'] = df.loc[:, 'last'].map(role_dict)
```

Comment: Giving this a shot - interesting twist in my real use case is that the 'last' value appears to be a label in my dataframe, so `df['last']` gives a `KeyError: 'last'`. Any ideas there?

Comment: Ok, interesting, in that case it might be better to use `loc` to avoid the string 'last' to be mistaken by a row label. Chek the edit.

Answer (score 0):

try this using merge

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["Jon","McSmith"],
                  ["Jennifer","Foobar"],
                  ["Dan","Raizman"],
                  ["Alden","Lowe"]],columns=["first","last"])

role_dict = {
    "Raizman": "sales",
    "McSmith": "analyst",
    "Foobar": "analyst",
    "Lowe": "designer"
}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(role_dict.items(),columns=["last","role"])

result = pd.merge(df,df_2,on=["last"],how="left")
```

output

```
      first     last      role
0       Jon  McSmith   analyst
1  Jennifer   Foobar   analyst
2       Dan  Raizman     sales
3     Alden     Lowe  designer
```